# Render multiple elements based on number of keys in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have my object `videoId` that has these values:

[image]

I would like to render multiple `Player` components based on number of keys in the object, in this case that would be 2 `Player` components. Also each `Player` component should have different `src` attribute value. This value is represented in object as the `file` attribute.

So far I have tried to use `map()` function and I managed to get the `file` attribute from every key, but I have no idea how can I generate the `Player` components. Here is my code:

```
const response = await dataProvider(GET_MANY, 'vid', { ids: videoId })
const file = response.data;

let formsPerFile = file.map(async f => {
   var sigkey = "key";
   var formBody = new FormData();
   formBody.set('ver', "1.2");
   formBody.set('key', "key");
   formBody.set('video_id', f.file);
   formBody.set('user_id', "1234");
   formBody.set('format', "json");
   formBody.set('ip', "");
   formBody.set('tts', "0");
   formBody.set('nonce', Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000));

   var sign_fields = [formBody.get('video_id'), formBody.get('user_id'), formBody.get('ip'), formBody.get('tts'), formBody.get('ver'), formBody.get('key'), formBody.get('nonce')];
   var data = sign_fields.join(':');
   var signature = hmacsha256(data, sigkey);

   formBody.set('sig', signature);

   var formBodyStringified = new URLSearchParams(formBody).toString();

   const resJson = await fetch(Config.api.livebox, {
         method: 'POST',
         body: formBodyStringified,
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
         }
         }).then(res => res.json());
                return 'https:' + resJson.hls;
 });
 this.setState({ multipleVideoSource: formsPerFile });
```

This code stores into state each `file` attribute.

And then in my `render()` method:

```
render()
    {
        const { multipleVideoSource }  = this.state;
        return multipleVideoSource ? <Player key={multipleVideoSource} height={500} fluid={false}>
            <ControlBar autoHide={false} className="my-class" />
            <BigPlayButton position="center"/>
            <HLSSource isVideoChild src={multipleVideoSource} />
        </Player> : "No video";
    }
```

Any ideas how can I render multiple `Player` components?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So is the question basically you want to render a `Player` component per key in the `videoId` object, while also removing ones with duplicate `src` attributes?

Comment: I dont want to remove anything, the src will always be different. I just want to render a Player component per key in the videoId object. And each of those components would have different src based on file attribute. Hope thats clear.

Comment: @AdamSulc Is `multipleVideoSource` an object or an array?

Comment: @UmairSarfraz it is an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea how can I generate the Player components

Use map to loop through the `multipleVideoSource` list.

```
{
  multipleVideoSource.map(src => (
    <Player key={src} src={src} />
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does render the components.

Answer (score 4):

Loop through the object keys and pass each object `videoId` as a prop to `Player` component.

```
Object.keys(multipleVideoSource).map((key) => (
    <Player key={key} src={multipleVideoSource[key]} />
));
```

Comment: That does work too, however @Joseph D. solved this first. Thank you though.